# In a pool, who executes the EVM code?

Tags: mining, mining-pools

Does the central pool server run the EVM code and just send out block headers, or does every miner run every contract?

Answer (score 1):

every miner runs every contract. there's no central pool server

Update: There actually central pool servers which dispatch work to the miners, but as far as my knowledge goes, every miner actually runs the contracts to validate them. (thanks to Nicolas's comment)

Comment: Yes there is a central pool server. It's what dispatches the work for miners.